# display URL in blackberry application

Tags: url, blackberry, java-me, blackberry-simulator

i have blackberry application and i try to display html text in a browser

i try

```
BrowserSession bSession = Browser.getDefaultSession();
bSession.displayPage("http://www.blackberry.com");
```

this page success but it display page in blackberry browser not in my own browser, and i don't need that

than i try

```
myBrowserField = new BrowserField();
add(myBrowserField);
myBrowserField.requestContent("http://www.blackberry.com");
```

this method displays error 104

and i try

```
BrowserFieldRequest test = new BrowserFieldRequest("http://www.blackberry.com");
BrowserField myBrowserField = new BrowserField();
add(myBrowserField);
myBrowserField.requestContent(test);
```

the last 2 methods

it gives no error and display empty browser but after 120 seconds it gives connection timeout

**Note:** i try different url but it didn't solve the problem

any help,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the `BrowserField`,

1. If you are using a simulator, you should enable MDS-CS (Mobile Data System Connection Service)  for the `BrowserField` to work properly (I don't know any other way). If MDS-CS is not enabled, follow this guide "[Testing a BlackBerry device application with the BlackBerry Smartphone Simulator](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/35144/Testing_a_BB_app_with_BB_smartphone_sim_1889924_11.jsp)" on how to enable it.
2. If the MDS-CS is enabled, but you are using JRE 7.0.0 (9930 simulator), then the problem is that the MDS-CS version supplied with JRE 7.0.0 is incorrect (the symptom is that the MDS-CS window doesn't show up when you run the simulator). Check my answer for "[Blackberry BrowserField error in Simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9369795/396949)" or "[Blackberry webview can not connect to internet and/or display a web page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9369634/396949)" for more details and instructions.

Hope that one of the aforementioned will work for you.

Comment: how can delete mds-cs file from blackberry jre 7 file and add it from blackberry jre 6.
did you know any site to download blackberry jre 6 from it
i googled but i didn't find it
thanks MrVincenzo

Comment: @mbayloon Delete `EclipsePath\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack7.0.0_xxx\components\MDS` and replace it with this MDS `EclipsePath\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack6.0.0_yyyy\components\MDS`. Restart Eclipse before rerunning the application. `EclipsePath` is your path to Eclipse, usually `c:\eclipse`.

Comment: in eclipse path i have \plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack7.0.0_xxx\components\MDS. but i don't have \plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack6.0.0_yyyy\components\MDS to replace with. (i don't have this file componentpack6.0.0_yyyy) if you have it can uou send it to my email (mbayloon@gmail.com) thanks MrVincenzo

Comment: You can install JRE 6.0.0 via the BlackBerry's update site. Follow [this guide](http://us.blackberry.com/developers/javaappdev/javaupdate.jsp) to lear how